# Android Studio v.2021.1.1- How to install plugin from disk

Tags: android-studio, plugins

in the Android Studio 2021.1.1, I am not seeing any portal to install plugin from disk
[Preference->Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXRD1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXRD1.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image: You would find it in the icon surrounded by light blue square]
In the light blue circle, you can find the option of adding plugin from the disk.